# If a vector v is an eigenvector of both matrices A and B, is V an eigenvector of A+B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If so, is there a proof for this?

I have been stuck trying to validate the statement and would love some insight.

Answer (score 5):

$$Ax = \lambda x, Bx = \mu x, x \neq 0 \implies (A+B)x = (\lambda+\mu)x .$$ That is, $\lambda + \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B$ and the corresponding  eigenvector is $x.$

Answer (score 4):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ and $B\Rightarrow Av=\lambda_1 v$ and $Bv=\lambda_1v$ for some $\lambda_1, \lambda_2\in \mathbb{C} $. Now $(A+B)v=Av+Bv=\lambda_1 v+\lambda_2 v=(\lambda_1 +\lambda_2 )v$  implies that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A+B$